# How do I make my discord bot send an attachment when certain word is sent

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm new to working with discord bot and decided to try it out, to start I just wanted to make the bot send an attachment (image, video, etc) when for example, "sendpicture" is written in chat.

I've changed the code several times yet I get the same error everytime, "Attachment is not a constructor" or "Discord.Attachment is not a constructor".

My current code looks like this:

```
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once(`ready`, () => {
    console.log("online");
});

const PREFIX = "!"

//replying with a text message
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === 'test1') {
      msg.channel.send('working');
    }
  });
  
//replying with attachment
client.on("message", function(message){
   
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.lenght).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]) { 
        case "test2": 
            message.channel.send(new Discord.Attachment(`.a/this/bestpic.png`, `bestpic.png`) )
            .then(msg => {
                //aaaaaaaa
            })
            .catch(console.error);
            break;
    }
})
```

tyia

Answer (score 1):

Had you tried looking at the official ***[documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send)*** ?

I don't think you should use `new Discord.Attachment()`, try this instead :

```js
switch(args[0]) { 
    case "test2": 
        message.channel.send({
            files: [{
                attachment: '.a/this/bestpic.png',
                name: 'bestpic.png'
            }]
        }).then(msg => {
                //aaaaaaaa
        }).catch(console.error);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Discord.Attachment() is not a thing, i believe the answer you are looking for is this :)

```
new Discord.MessageAttachment()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, short and simple to use.

```js
if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'word') { //only word, without prefix
        message.channel.send({ files: ['./path_to_your_file'] })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using MessageAttachment because Discord.Attachment is not a thing, then add the attachment into the files property

I would consider making the attachment a variable instead of putting it directly into the function, it is optional tho

```js
const { MessageAttachment } = require("discord.js");

const attachment = new MessageAttachment("url", "fileName(optional)", data(optional));

message.channel.send({ files: [attachment] }).then(//code...)
```

Let me know if it works